# can't receive a notification after posting inside connectionDidFinishLoading:, NSURLConnection delegate method

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsurlconnection, nsnotificationcenter

I can't receive a notification with this:

a class for doing NSURLConnection async stuff

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {

    NSDictionary *userInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:_receivedData, @"receivedData", nil];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kWebServiceURLTemperaturaMaximaKMLNotitificationName object:self userInfo:userInfo];

}
```

another class observing the notification:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceivedCompleteData:) name:kWebServiceURLTemperaturaMaximaKMLNotitificationName object:self];
```

any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is here:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didReceivedCompleteData:) name:kWebServiceURLTemperaturaMaximaKMLNotitificationName object:self];
```

This means that notification center will send notification named `name:kWebServiceURLTemperaturaMaximaKMLNotitificationName` to `self` that is also generated by `self`. You should replace `object:self` with `object:nil` (to receive any notification named `name:kWebServiceURLTemperaturaMaximaKMLNotitificationName`) or with object that is actually sending the notification.

Comment: Thanks, that was dumb of my part.